# Make external link to page by angular - I can't go to external page

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

And question is:

How to make links on html or ts working?
I need some links to external pages on my app. I have user profile and profile I have links to social accounts of this user, (eg. `instagram.com/sisterofclara`) but on this form:

```
<div class="col-md-12"  *ngFor="let currentAccountObject of user.userContact.accounts">
   <div class="margin-10-px" >
       <div class="col-md-1 font-bold"> 
          <img[src]="getIcon(currentAccountObject.socialAccountType)">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-9 font-bold"> {{currentAccountObject.login}}
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I can go nowhere, because my links always have `localhost:3000` before phrase when I'm clicking on it. Always.

I tried to make click function on angular with `uri` as argument, and function looks like that:

```
 public goToProfile(url) {
    window.location.href = url;
  }
```

i tried it by click, i tried a `href={{person.link}}`, I tried this function, I tried also `location.replace(uri)` but nothing is work (because of adding my `localhost` a the beginning). Why?

Edit: this is html:

```
 <div class="row col-md-12 contact">
            <div *ngIf="contactTabEditable==false">
              <div class="col-md-12 ro-label" align="left">Social media:</div>
              <div class="col-md-10 social-media">
                <div>
                  <div class="col-md-12"  *ngFor="let currentAccountObject of user.userContact.accounts">
                      <div class="margin-10-px" >
                          <div class="col-md-1 font-bold"><img [src]="getIcon(currentAccountObject.socialAccountType)"></div>
                          <div *ngIf="currentAccountObject.link" class="col-md-9 font-bold"> 
                            <a (click)="goToProfile(currentAccountObject.link)"> {{currentAccountObject.login}} </a>
                          </div>
                          <!-- <div *ngIf="!showClickableAccount" class="col-md-9 font-bold"> {{currentAccountObject.login}}</div> -->
                      </div>
                 </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use a `<a href="externalUrl">` element
If you want to use databinding, to bind to your elemtent, you can use the following:

```html
<a [attr.href]="url"></a>
```

If you have the a variable in your component that is called url eg:

```js
public url = "https://google.com/";
```

Another option would be:

```html
<a href="{{url}}">URL</a>
```

Or if you have a field for user that contains his instagram name:
Taken from [Docs](https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference#bind-to-the-href-property):

```html
<a [href]="'https://www.instagram.com/' + user.instagramName">URL</a>
```

Comment: I thinked about this solution, but problem is in form. I can't use public variable because i have few links from few accounts and this account data are showing by *ngFor, not as a phrase so I don't know is this account is istagram or something different.

Comment: Can you post a minimum working example of your code?
Maybe I can work something out then

Answer (score 0):

I solved that issue using below code

hope it will help you.

Just replace your function with below code

```
public goToProfile(url: string) {
        let u: string = '';
        if (!/^http[s]?:\/\//.test(url)) {
          u += 'http://';
        }
        u += url;
        let link = this.document.createElement("a");
        link.target = '_blank';
        link.href = u;
        link.setAttribute('visibility', 'hidden');
        link.click();
    }
```

add document in your constructor

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any){}
```

and import DOCUMENT like

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

let me know if you need any more help

thanks

Comment: what are you passing into parameter ? (I mean value)

Comment: click on this link and run the code

http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgUwhAhgcwQLhtATgSzDRgF4YByACwQBsaQYB3EXGgE3IG4AoUSEGggB09NAApEydAgCUPAGYBXMMCj5wMAEaKoUcMBr5gAazGLWMbHkJoZMAN7cYzl88GxFVqASKkKXJ1cXfHkYMQBCAHoAPUpdAAcAbQgAXQB+TAAdSOzIoSgkKDNWGTtHIKDFGABqMioEzEjIgIrnAF9AiqramHMaHlaYdyHCYz82EGBFRDAoIWBcBBQCgFFBGaKAIhRNuU6gwzBjfJRcDFg6gH1NGhQjltbD48pF0LJFAcfRoQgEKABBXQEbQFMTkABu+Ag+E0+EMUAAnuQADQUSj4NhsBBgch7QZPeaGExiPYdEF6FRE0zkQjQdC4FBweYgOCRaHQBC4EDyAynFC4njcIA

Answer (score 0):

Just try the following code. I hope it works for you.

```
<a href="website_address" target="”_blank”" rel="noopener noreferrer">Text</a>
```